# MVC many to many get entities with of certain type only in code first

Tags: linq, linq-to-sql, many-to-many, code-first

I have a many to many relationship between Company and CompanyType

I want to get a list for a dropdown of only Companies with a CompanyType.Name of "Client". I.e. a clientCompanyList.

How can I do that in linq?

I basically wanted to do the following but in linq

```
var clientCompanies = db.Companies.SqlQuery(@"SELECT  c.*
FROM    Companies AS c
JOIN    CompanyTypeCompanies AS ctc ON ctc.Company_ID = c.ID
JOIN    CompanyTypes AS ct ON ctc.CompanyType_ID = ct.ID
WHERE   ct.Name = 'Client'").ToList();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use include statement, if it having proper foreign key relation ships between tables

```
var clientCompanies = db.CompanyTypes
.Where(ct => ct.Name == "Client").Include(ct => ct.CompanyTypeCompanies).Include(ct => ct.Companies).Select(ct => ct.Companies).ToList();
```

In startup class

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    ...

    services.AddMvc()
        .AddJsonOptions(
            options => options.SerializerSettings.ReferenceLoopHandling = Newtonsoft.Json.ReferenceLoopHandling.Ignore
        );

    ...
}
```